# elasticsearch compound query on two fields

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to write a complex elastic search query. I know how to write them separately. But don't know how to combine them. I have two fields in doc.(paid(boolean) and money(float)). I want all the docs where paid=false and money>0. This is what I have done.

```
GET /_search
{
    "query": {
        "range" : {
            "money" : {
                "gte" : 0,
                "lte" :1000
            }
        }
    }
} 
GET /_search
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "paid": false 
    }
  }
}
```

EDIT1

now if I have a nested field I want to search on that as well.

```
GET /_search
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "sellers_info",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "match": {
                "sellers_info.seller_label": "Owner"
              }
            }

          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How to combine these three?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great start! Simply combine them with [`bool/filter`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html), like this:

```
GET /_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "paid": false
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "money": {
              "gte": 0,
              "lte": 1000
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: can you suggest some resources on how to combine queries?

Comment: You can start by clicking the link I posted ;-)

Comment: Simply add it to the filter array like the other constraints